# How can i avoid the "i" dependency in this loop? Fortran

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I'm working with OpenMP in my code, but in order to do that I have to solve this dependency:

```
do q=1,pppp
    i=0
    
    DO j=1, pppp
        do c1=1,3
            vect(c1)=xx(q,c1)-xx(j,c1)
        end do
        dist=sqrt(vect(1)**2+vect(2)**2+vect(3)**2)
        if(dist<0.0001)then
            i=i+1
            if(i>10)i=10
            caravec(q,i)=j
        endif
    ENDDO
ENDDO
```

I'm trying to avoid the `ordered` clause, because it is expensive, but I don't know how to remove the dependency. How can I do that?
Thanks for all the help

Comment: I do not know FORTRAN, but I know OpenMP and I think if you parallelize the outmost loop and make `i` (and `vect` and `dist`) private, there is no problem with it.

Comment: You should consider unrolling the c1 loop and inlining the vect(c1) computations to avoid a number of not very helpful array indexes.  Maybe  your compiler is aggressive enough.

Comment: The (conditional) assignment to caravec(q,i)=j   leaves many elements of caravec uninitialized (garbage).   How is later code to know which elements of caravec are valid/safe to use?  If this computation isn't right, then its unclear what to do with the dependency.  (Maybe Fortran initializes arrays to zero?)

Comment: It would help if you show us what you are trying at the moment - as you assert one part is "expensive" presumably you have measured that. Also testing n distance squared rather than distance will avoid the call to `sqrt`, Finally the language is officially spelt Fortran, and has been so for over 3 decades.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few Fortran things you can do to improve on [@dreamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837805/1366871)' excellent answer:

- Fortran is [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), so you want to iterate over left-most indices in inner loops, not right-most indices. So you should probably transpose `xx`, so it's a `3*pppp` array indexed as `xx(c1,q)` rather than a `pppp*3` array indexed as `xx(q,c1)`.
- You probably want to use whole-array operations rather than single-element operations, as these have a better chance of being vectorised.
- You can store the result of `dist<0.0001` rather than `dist`.
- You can replace the `if (i>10)...` with a `min` statement, which will be branchless and so likely run faster.

So the code would look something like:

```
do q=1,pppp        
  do j=1,pppp
    vect = xx(:,q)-xx(:,j)
    within_tolerance(j, q) = dot_product(vect, vect) < 1.0e-8
  enddo
enddo

do q=1,pppp
  i=0    
  do j=1,pppp
    if (within_tolerance(j, q)) then
      i = min(i+1, 10)
      caravec(q,i)=j
    endif
  enddo
enddo
```

You may also want to transpose `caravec`, but this will depend on how it is used elsewhere.

### An [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) solution

If this is the bottleneck of your code, you might want to look into voxel-based methods for finding nearest-neighbours within sets of vectors. A quick google brings up e.g. [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-40602-7_33).

Voxel methods remove the need for the double loop over `q` and `j`, which can potentially let you do these kinds of comparisons much faster.

On the other hand, voxel methods are quite complicated, and I don't think they're appropriate for all circumstances (e.g. if you have very dense regions of points and very sparse regions of points then I think a voxel method would struggle).

Comment: "You can store the result of dist<0.0001 rather than dist." Very good point, nice answer btw. Just a curiosity from a non Fortran programmer. "You can replace the if (i>10)... with a min statement, which will be branchless and so likely run faster." Doesn't this depend upon on how min is implemented underneath? For example, in java Math.min still uses ">" underneath. Do you know how it is in Fortran ?

Comment: @dreamcrash yeah, it does depend on the implementation, and the fact that `i` is immediately used as an index probably limits the room for speedup in this case. But most Fortran implmentations I'm aware of (mainly gfortran and ifort) use the dedicated `min` and `max` processor instructions, so things can end up entirely branchless.

Comment: You might be able to do even better by finding the first 9 values which satisfy the loop, exiting the loop and the go backwards from the end to find the 10th. Depends on the structure of the data.

Answer (score 5):

**DISCLAIMER:** I have never programmed with Fortan. So my code most-likely has bugs.

But using logic and assuming that what you have stated is correct *i.e.,* that the only dependency is the 'i' variable. You can try the following:

```
do q=1,pppp        
    DO j=1, pppp
        do c1=1,3
            vect(c1)=xx(q,c1)-xx(j,c1)
        end do
        dist(q,j)=sqrt(vect(1)**2+vect(2)**2+vect(3)**2)
    ENDDO
ENDDO
```

So you parallelize the outer loop with OpenMP. This way you can run in parallel the most computational demanding part of the loop without the 'i' dependency. Notice that I am saving the result of the distances into a vector.

Then sequentially you can do the remaining loop computation as follows:

```
do q=1,pppp
    i=0    
    DO j=1, pppp
        if(dist(q,j) < 0.0001)then
            i=i+1
            if(i>10)i=10
            caravec(q,i)=j
        endif
    ENDDO
ENDDO
```

The downside of the current approach is that besides requiring refactoring of the code it also uses more memory than the original one. On the other hand it removes the need for synchronization among threads.

As [@Ian Bush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280439/ian-bush) mentioned in the comments you can further improve your sequential code by

> testing n distance squared rather than distance will avoid the call
> to sqrt